# display data together from 2 different SQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to display details from  2 different tables

Table 1- user table

Table 2-bicycle table

I can show a list of users and bicycle.

But can't show a list that show which bicycle belongs to who.
[Bicycle table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPFUz.jpg),
[user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWAgt.jpg)

Comment: And neither can we, as we have **absolutely no idea what your database tables look like** There are a lot of clever people that haunt this site, but **none of them are clairvoyant**

Comment: What is your sql code? Instead of screenshots would be better to show your fields and field types inlaid in question

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN`. The query below will connect your `user` table to your `bicycle` table based on the `userID`and return all of the bicycle and user fields

```
SELECT b.*, u.*
FROM registered_users u
LEFT JOIN registered_bicycle b ON (u.userID = b.userID)
```

If you want specific bicycle fields just prefix them with `b.` Example:

`SELECT b.brand, b.model, b.color...`

Answer (score 0):

Click on SQL tab and type this:

```
SELECT * FROM `registered_bicycle` JOIN `registered_users` ON `registered_users`.`userID` = `registered_bicycle`.`userID`
```

and run it

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a foreign key from user_table to bicycle_table like this.

```
 user_table has user_id = user_1,name=John Richard
 bicycle_table has user_id = user_1,description = Bicycle1
 to fetch the data:
```

```
      select a.user_id, a.name,b.description from
     (select user_id, name from user_table) as a
      left join
     (select user_id,description from bicycle_table) as b
      on a.user_id = b.user_id
```